# Firebase Storage IO Exception

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I've been trying to download a PDF file from Firebase Storage and storing it in ***local storage***, not external.

Exception occurring:

> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

Code for downloading the file and storing it:

```
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(fileDetails.getFileUrl());

        File rootPath = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "notesApp");
        if (!rootPath.exists()) {
            rootPath.mkdirs();
        }

        final File myFile = new File(rootPath,fileDetails.getFileName()+".pdf");

        storageRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Local temp file has been created
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Log.e("Download Failed: ",exception.toString());
            }
        });
```

Logcat for exception:

```
    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:136)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:227)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-09-18 20:38:01.109 32195-32312/com.example.android.notes E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
2019-09-18 20:38:01.156 32195-32312/com.example.android.notes E/StorageException: No such file or directory
    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:136)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:227)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-09-18 20:38:01.163 32195-32312/com.example.android.notes E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
2019-09-18 20:38:01.242 32195-32312/com.example.android.notes E/StorageException: No such file or directory
    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.processResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:136)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:227)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-09-18 20:38:40.889 32195-32195/com.example.android.notes E/Download Failed:: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
```

Edit:

Replaced  `File rootPath = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "notesApp");`
with
 `File rootPath = new File(getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), "notesApp");`

Now only error that shows is:

`error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.`

Comment: the provided file path not valid

Comment: What should I use?

Comment: that problem has httpresult 0....I'm getting 200 i.e OK

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly the string returned by `fileDetails.getFileUrl()`. I don't think it is what you think it is.

Comment: That stores the URL to the file and it is correct I'm sure about it. PDF does open in a browser upon entering that URL

Comment: your storage reference i think needs to be something like this `storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://my-project.appspot.com/test_image.png")` and please post hte

Comment: Please check edited answer